# installing crx-less web apps

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

To install CRX-less Web Apps a manifest.json file is required.
Then the function chrome.app.install() has to be called.
Logically the app should install, but it doesn´t. Chrome informs me then about a but:

```
TypeError: Property 'install' of object #<Object> is not a function
Enable is about:flags
```

It could be the case that the "CRX-less Web Apps" flag has to be activated, but this isn´t possible in the way as described in the [chrome docs](https://developers.google.com/chrome/apps/docs/no_crx#enable) in the newest versions of Google Chrome or Chrome Canary.

Hopefully someone knows an answer to the problem.

A not working example is http://www.htmlfivewow.com/demos/terminal/terminal.html. You can try it by simply typing *install*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CRX-less apps experiment has been removed from Chrome (at [revision 188261](http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome?view=revision&revision=188261)).

The error you report is because `typeof chrome.app.install` is `"undefined"`.

I have filed issues
[245161](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=245161) to clean up doc, and [245162](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=245162) to remove chrome.app.install.

Comment: Thank you, didn´t knew that.

Comment: So basically, all apps that have been created with it can't be used now anymore? or is there some alternative?